# How can I differentiate the recurring amount from initial amount in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe in my website. Is there any possibilities to send 2 different amounts into Stripe. One is initial amount and the second one is recurring amount, both are different.

I would like to register the user with $10 for the first time, and I don't want to collect same amount $10 for every month as recurring amount. I just want to continue the subscription with the amount $5.

I have verified in Stripe documents but didn't notice any thing helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Stripe `Billing`[0] will fulfill most your subscription related user case.

There are several way to do this. For example,

1. You could create a one-off invoice to charge the user $10s and then Subscribe the user to the $5 plan with 1 month trial[1] or a 100% discount coupon for the first month[2]
2. You could create two pricing plans for your product one with $10 per month and another $5 dollars. Subscribe the user to $10 dollars and then downgrade the subscription to $5 dollar plan[3] (This will give you some flexibility on how long you want charge the user for $10 dollars)

   - [0] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart
   - [1] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials
   - [2] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts
   - [3] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrading-downgrading#switching

Comment: Thanks for your help, but here my main concern is I needs to send 2 amounts at a time to the Stripe. Initial amount and Recurring amount. Recurring amount may varry based on user. It may be $5 for one user, $6 for another user. I am sorry if I confuses you.